# About the new modifier in C#

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I don't quite understand the modifier`new` in C#: In which way is the following code different depending on the presence of the `new` modifier?

```
class A 
    {
        public void F() { Console.WriteLine("A::F()"); }
    }


class B : A
    {
    public new void F() { Console.WriteLine("B::F()"); }

    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new B();
        B b = new B();
        A trueA = new A();
        a.F();
        b.F();
        trueA.F();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Is there any equivalent or similar thing in C++?

Comment: I think you meant [new operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)

Comment: @Habib Given that the code won't even compile if the `new` operator was removed, I think OP means the `new` modifier.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, I think the code would compile but it will only give a warning for method hiding. And yes you are right the OP is asking about method hiding and not the new operator.

Comment: Are you asking why `a.F` and `trueA.F()` both return `"A::F()"`, even though `a` is instantiated as `new B()`? I don't quite get the question.

Comment: Second part (C++ equivalent of C# "new modifier") is covered in [Can you Hide a virtual method in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828009/can-you-hide-a-virtual-method-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

The result is the same if you are using `public void F()` or `public new void F()` in the class `B`. The method will still be shadowed.

The difference is that if you omit the `new` modifier, you will get a compiler warning because the code may be confusing. The `new` modifier is used to specify that you actually intended to shadow a member from the base class, and didn't just happen to use the same name by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You would see differences if you defined in the base class the method virtual. The override modifier extends the base class method, and the new modifier hides it by creating a new method which has nothing to do with one on the base class.
Try next code :

```
class Program
{
 class A
 {
   public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("A::F()"); }
   public virtual void G() { Console.WriteLine("A::G()"); }
 }


class B : A
{
  public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("B::F()"); }
  public new void G() { Console.WriteLine("B::G()"); }

  public static void Main()
  {
    A a = new B();
    B b = new B();
    a.F();
    b.F();
    a.G();
    b.G();

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

}

In C++ you can hide a method of the base class by defining a method on the derived class with the same name but different parameters. Maybe you can use that.